# Config file of FOSRestBundle 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.8, symfony-config-component

I'm looking for configuration's path of FOSRestBundle 2.3.
I have Symfony 2.8.

I have checked app/config/config.yml but nothing about fos_rest :/

When I type PHP app/console config:debug fos_rest I got the configuration of this bundle.

Please help !

Answer (score -1):

I have current configuration for my bundle.

```
# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/filemanager', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/html', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }

param_fetcher_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        json: true
exception:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I'm looking for the path for change the configuration, I can't find it !!